# Identify the member server in a Active Directory domain network which made logon attempt (failed) in the logs of Domain Controller

Tags: windows, active-directory, audit-logging, domaincontroller

I want to find the member server from which the logon attempt (failed) was made in the logs of a domain controller. Is there a way to find the IP or computer name of the machine which is trying to authenticate?

I am getting a credential validation (audit failure) event logged into the domain controller which is giving the workstation name of the server outside the network which is attacking the member server with invalid credentials. But what I need is to find the machine in my AD which it is hitting on.

Comment: Doesn't the event data in your log have the IP address?

Comment: I can see the IP address of the attacker (sometimes not). But I want to know the member server which he is attacking on.